# On a theorem of Akizuki concerning the minimal number of generators of an ideal

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am looking for a theorem of Akizuki I was told by my professor. He said me that Akizuki showed in his paper "Zur Idealtheorie der einartigen Ringbereiche mit dem Teilerkettensatz" (1938) a result like the following:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain satisfying some hypotheses (local, one dimensional? My professor didn't remember). Then there exists $m \ge 1$ such that every ideal of $R$ is generated by at most $m$ elements.

I cannot find a reference for this theorem in English, so I would like if someone can give me the precise statement of this theorem, and maybe provide me a proof in English.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The correct title seems to be "Zur Idealtheorie der einartigen Ringbereiche mit dem Teilerkettensatz". See https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/result/-char/ja/?cdjournal=jjm1924&item1=4&word1=Zur+Idealtheorie+der+einartigen+Ringbereiche+mit+dem+Teilerkettensatz and http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195579999 for online copies.

Comment: The domain must be of Krull Dimension 1

Comment: Here is the [reference][https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjm1924/15/0/15_0_1/_pdf] for the document you stated.

For the converse, an integral domain with the property that there exists an integer $m$ such that every ideal can be generated with fewer than $m$ elements must be Noetherian and of Krull dimension $1$. It was proven by Cohen in [Commutative Rings with Restricted Minimum Condition] [https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077475897]

Comment: @Elaqqad When I click on links you gave me, it gives me error, not found.

Comment: @Crostul, the document is in german: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjm1924/15/0/15_0_1/_pdf

Comment: @Elaqqad: I could not find the result in the first article you linked; this chapter seems to be concerned only with the case $m=3$. However, it is proven (along with its converse) in Theorem 9 on page 35 in Cohen's article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Remy pointed out in comments the result is Theorem 9 in Cohen's paper [Commutative rings with restricted minimum condition](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077475897), which says the following

> Let $R$ be a local Noetherian domain. Then $\dim R\le1$ iff there exists $m\ge1$ such that every ideal of $R$ is $m$-generated.

**Remark.** For $\dim R\le1$ the "mysterious" $m$ can be chosen the multiplicity of $R$.